# Download Git LFS files without checkout

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm looking for a way to download some git LFS zip files I have in a repo without having to checkout the entire repository.

I have tried the following:

`curl -L <URL to the file RAW download on github page>`

- This downloads a html file and not the actual file.

`curl -L <URL from .lfsconfig file + object ID from the file's pointer information in git repo>`

- Gives a "Not found" error

More example tries:

```
curl  -L https://gitlfs.es.com/api/company/myrepository/content/framework/7d5dfcf764118df4867dc676b615e1ee4bf67e5b37fd56275f8845d
 
curl  -L https://gitlfs.es.com/api/company/myrepository/7d5dfcf764118df4d188d5838867dc676b615e1ee4bf67e5b37fd56275f8
 
curl  -L https://gitlfs.es.com/api/company/myrepository/sha256:7d5dfcf764118df4d188d5838867dc676b615e1ee4bf67e5b37fd56275f8845d
```

None of the above seems to work

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: The URL schema is described here: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/batch.md

Answer (score 1):

If the repository is private then you need to pass either Gitlab authorization token or account authentication credentials in curl command.

You may find links below useful:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a 2 step process:

Step 1: Get the CDN url, as it cant download with redirected url (Need the auth token if private, else ignore that)
curl -I -0 "<binary_path>" -H "Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>"

Step 2: use the location cdn url to dump the file
curl "" -o output_filename